# How can I import data from this .dat file

Tags: python, excel, data-files

I have data in a file that looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the file]

As you can see the data is very neat, but it is not separated in a concise fashion, but rather a variable number of spaces between columns and some columns left blank. This makes it import incorrectly into, for example, Excel. I have tried import functions in spyder and sage. I did not create the file.

Comment: This is a fixed width file, excel offers solutions for importing such data.

Comment: The spaces between columns look consistent to me... The columns themselves have variable amount of sizes

Comment: Tried pandas? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html

Comment: Thanks guys, that turned out to be the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fixed width file, so using pandas with python is the way to go:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html

Answer (score 0):

try import it and see what you get.

```
media = []
with open("filename.dat", "r") as f:
    media.append(f.readlines())
for row in media:
    do something with row
```

on 2nd thought it looks like it may be tab-delimited:

```
import csv
with open("filename.dat", "rB") as f:
    csv_file = csv.reader(f, deilmiter='\t')
for row in csv_file:
    do something with row
```